# Nested Route Implicit Binding Laravel Return 404

Tags: php, laravel, routes, model-binding, nested-routes

So, this is my code.

##### `web.php`

```php
Route::get(
    "/research/{research}/sub-research/{sub-research}", 
    function (Research $research, SubResearch $subResearch) {
        dd($research , $subResearch);
    }
)
    ->name("sub-research.show");
```

##### Research model

```php
public function subResearch()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SubResearch::class, "research_id", "id");
}
```

##### SubResearch.php model

```php
public function research()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Research::class);
}
```

My problem is, when I access the route, I got [404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg9Gj.png). Laravel's documentation says:

> When using a custom keyed implicit binding as a nested route parameter, Laravel will automatically scope the query to retrieve the nested model by its parent using conventions to guess the relationship name on the parent. In this case, it will be assumed that the **`User`** model has a relationship named **`posts`** (the plural form of the route parameter name) which can be used to retrieve the **`Post`** model.

How can I know what is laravel guessing as my relationship method name? Is it the same or not? Or maybe is this some other problem? What do you think?

Comment: your using route model binding so you need to add in your Model the function `getRouteKeyName`. see: [Laravel 10](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing)

Comment: using ``getRouteKeyName`` and ``return 'id'`` ? @SandroJhulianoCagara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route segment name have to be the same to the route function variable name.Use {subResearch} instead of {sub-research}

```
Route::get(
    "/research/{research}/sub-research/{subResearch}", 
    function (Research $research, SubResearch $subResearch) {
        dd($research , $subResearch);
    }
)
    ->name("sub-research.show");
```